# How to fit an image to a flex item with max-height restriction on its ancestor?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I have a reusable component to display two horizontal sections shared with same shape. The two sections are distributed evenly based on there content.

I post the component in https://jsfiddle.net/kezhuw/7pzmgz6c/2/.

I post a modified version in https://jsfiddle.net/kezhuw/7pzmgz6c/3/ with the desired vision, but it set direct restriction `max-height` on the `img` tag.

The `max-height` restriction should be set on component level, served as API.

Some notes:

- The two sections in the component has `flex: 1 1 auto;`, it is a method to achieve "distributed evenly based on there content".
- With max height of the component restricted, the title of section two should be the longest horizontal content in this component. Space should be distributed around this. But it is not, due to `object-fit: contain;`. Without `object-fit: contains;`, the image fill its parent div wholly. You can see it in https://jsfiddle.net/kezhuw/7pzmgz6c/4/.

HTML:
<-- language: lang-html -->

```
<div class="device">
  <div class="app">

    <div class="component">
      <div class="section section1">
        <div class="logo">
          <img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="title">Section One</div>
      </div>
      <div class="section section2">
        <div class="logo">
          <img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="title">Section Two: Another Title Here, Longer than first</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="another-component">
      Another component
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.device {
  width: 600px;
  height: 1200px;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  border: thick solid purple;
}

.app > * {
  min-height: 0;
}

.component {
  /*
   * max-height is an API exposed by this component,
   * used by client to restrict max height of component.
   *
   * This API is exposed as raw css style, not an Vue/React prop.
   *
   * As an Vue/React Prop, it is possible to calculate max-height of image
   * from this prop. I think this calculation process  is not maintainable and the result
   * may not accurate.
   *
   * Another way to solve this problem is to treat this max-height as the restriction
   * of image, not the component. But I think that may not be friend to consumer.
   */
  max-height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  border: thick solid lightseagreen;
}

.component > * {
  min-width: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.section1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  /* Align from bottom to top, to fix title at the bottom,
   * even if there is no logo for this section.
   */
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.section > * {
  min-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  /* Don't shrink title */
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.logo {
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo > * {
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

.image {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  /* max-height: 70px; */
}

.another-component {
  font-size: 30px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}
```